# LOST .p12 key for Air Published App in Google Play- Can I create same finger print?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, google-play, key, fingerprint

I reformatted my drive. Saved all but somehow the p12 is gone.
I tried uploading my .apk to Google Play, an existing app, signed with a new .p12
key and this is the error I get in the image.

[image]

Is there a way to make a new .p12 using the numbers they showed me?
Or can I abstract my old .p12 from an app I already uploaded and have copies
of?

Thank you for any advice in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a p12 like this, but you can try "migrate" the app to a new certificate, like described [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappsflex/WS13ACB483-1711-43c0-9049-0A7251630A7D.html)

I never actually tried this, though, so good luck!